# matlab matrix substitution without loops

Tags: matlab

below there is a task we were asked to do using matlab.
I wrote this function below which works fine.
But, since 'for' loops were not shown yet in the course, I think that the instructor meant doing it without loops.
Any ideas?
Thanks!

**By the way, How do I make new line in stackexchange editor?**
Thanks!

[image]
[image: Question 2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $m$, $n$ you can assign

$A(1:2:m,1:2:n)=1;$

$A(2:2:m,2:2:n)=1;$

P.S. Loops in MATLAB are in general slow, substitute it if possible by vector/matrix operations that MATLAB is optimized for.